# Node "interest" notification in drupal

Tags: drupal, triggers

My question is quite simple (i think) but cannot find the right module for that.

I'm working on a small classified website in which i have a bunch of nodes. I display them using views.

I'd like for any (authenticated with role) user of the website to be able to click on a kind of button like "I'm interested" which will trigger an event doing various actions like 'changing one cck field' on that content-type and also send an e-mail to the author of the classified.

Pretty straight forward but no clue on where to start, which module should i use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you can use the [Flag Module](http://drupal.org/project/flag) and [Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

In your view, you can create a relationship to flags to allow the use of other 'fields'.

Using Rules, create a new rule that is triggered when a node is flagged (or unflagged).  Rules allows you to do both: changing a CCK field and sending out emails when an event occurs.

**Walk-through:**

> 1. Install and enable the Flag Module and Rules Module
> 2. Create a new flag at "admin/build/flags"
> 3. Edit/Create you classified view, add a relationship to `Flags: Node Flag` and choose >     the name of the flag you just created.
> 4. Under "fields" add `Flags: Flag link` and configure as you like
> 5. Add a new rule at "admin/rules/trigger/add" for the event `A node has been flagged,
>
>      under "FLAG NAME"`
> 6. Add action to perform of `Populate a field` under the heading **CCK**
> 7. Add action to perform of `Send a mail to a user` under the heading **System**
>      and configure your desired settings.

Then when a user clicks the "interested" flag a field will be populated and email sent.

Comment: @Disco Added a walk-through in case it was needed.

Comment: Excellent ! Perfect ! Wunderbar ! Thank you veeery much ! 
Maybe you should write a blog post about this; really interesting

Comment: One more quick question; what if I need to have several users being able to flag a particular classified; in your example the 'populate' field will 'erase' previous interests.

Comment: What are you populating the field with? And where does that field need to be viewed?

Comment: forget it; was a stupid question. i will use views to see who flagged this node and reduce the count in cck)

Comment: Haha ok, that's what I was thinking.  And you're right, might be blog worthy ;)